# Wrong output while finding the root by Fixed Point Iteration

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I have an equation `g = @(x)(5-((5/2)*exp(x/2))-((7/2).x^2)-3*x).^1/3` and, according to specs, the equation has 3 roots. But my output does not have any match between x and g(x) in order to get Fixed Points. Output:

```
>> fpi1(g, 0.5, 20)
   x0                                           g(x0)
  0.500000000000000                       0.670818823114861 - 1.161892284308499i
  0.670818823114861 - 1.161892284308499i  1.281297751181495 - 1.559064591427071i
  1.281297751181495 - 1.559064591427071i  1.864118571141893 - 1.621766955715062i
  1.864118571141893 - 1.621766955715062i  2.320549078066838 - 1.504496934526923i
  2.320549078066838 - 1.504496934526923i  2.646646533032701 - 1.316018792060223i
  2.646646533032701 - 1.316018792060223i  2.870437643388612 - 1.115036747500670i
  2.870437643388612 - 1.115036747500670i  3.021682102842603 - 0.927806240969038i
  3.021682102842603 - 0.927806240969038i  3.123528510261589 - 0.763760920462736i
  3.123528510261589 - 0.763760920462736i  3.192243659445853 - 0.624547007383635i
  3.192243659445853 - 0.624547007383635i  3.238827490411373 - 0.508525243060542i
  3.238827490411373 - 0.508525243060542i  3.270613725640807 - 0.412880979787002i
  3.270613725640807 - 0.412880979787002i  3.292471687008435 - 0.334576282706924i
  3.292471687008435 - 0.334576282706924i  3.307635263738642 - 0.270756021961336i
  3.307635263738642 - 0.270756021961336i  3.318257296190301 - 0.218898831715851i
  3.318257296190301 - 0.218898831715851i  3.325776161489184 - 0.176850650328430i
  3.325776161489184 - 0.176850650328430i  3.331157314339334 - 0.142806525903066i
  3.331157314339334 - 0.142806525903066i  3.335052371178708 - 0.115272146831085i
  3.335052371178708 - 0.115272146831085i  3.337903988543196 - 0.093020017690524i
  3.337903988543196 - 0.093020017690524i  3.340015124633794 - 0.075047094363536i
  3.340015124633794 - 0.075047094363536i  3.341594884710001 - 0.060536697645525i
  3.341594884710001 - 0.060536697645525i  3.342788954448884 - 0.048825574318716i
```

What did I do wrong? How could it be fixed?

```
%Program 1.2 Fixed-Point Iteration
%Computes approximate solution of g(x)=x
%Input: inline function g, starting guess x0, 
%       number of steps k
%Output: Approximate solution xc
function xc=fpi1(g,x0,k)
x(1)=x0;
for i=1:k
  x(i+1)=g(x(i));
end
xc=x(k+1);
disp('   x0                                           g(x0)');
disp([x', g(x)']);
```

Comment: The `(7/2).x^2` in your formula for `g(x)` is giving me an error, because you're trying to use operator  `.` on a scalar. What operator do you intend for that to be?

Comment: @ClarissaG, but when I do not use operator `.` Matlab will give me error saying to use operator `.`

Comment: @ClarissaG, it gives me this: `Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.`

Comment: Please double check the function, there is a syntax error in it (`Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.`)

Comment: The corrected function should be: `g = @(x)(5-((5/2).*exp(x/2))-((7/2)*x.^2)-3*x).^1/3;`.  The dot after the `(7/2)` should be a multiply, and the power operators should be element-wise: `.^`.

Comment: @John - You can't use fixed point iterations to find roots.  The definition of a fixed point is the input value into a function is the same as the output value: `f(c) = c`.  The point of fixed point iterations is to find values that are fixed points in your function.  These are **not** used to find roots.  You need to use some other technique like Newton's Method or the Secant Method for that.  In any case, you are getting such high values for the function is because you probably have no fixed points in the function you specified.  If you want to find roots, use something else.

Comment: On a minor note, your fixed point code is correct... but you're using fixed point iterations for the wrong application.  If you want to find a root, that definition is where `f(c) = 0`.  Fixed points are `f(c) = c`.  The very definition of a root contradicts the definition of a fixed point **unless `c` = 0**, which it seldom is.

Comment: @rayryeng, but my projects specs specified to use FPI to calculate all three roots.

Comment: @John - It's possible, but you need to modify the function `g` so that it implements Newton's Method.  Would you like me to write an answer?

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks but no need to. Instead I fixed my code but none of values of x is equal g(x) in order to get the fixed point. Would you please take a look at the code above that I've changed? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You'd still need to modify it slightly to find the root.  I'll keep writing my answer.  However, your fixed point code (so far) is correct.

Comment: @rayryeng, but I don't think it outputs the right values for x and g(x). If you look at the output, the value of x is the previous value of g(x).

Comment: @John - Because you're not using it correctly to find roots.

Comment: @rayryeng, I understand your point, but here what projects specs say: **"Use Fixed Point Iteration to calculate all three roots. Each root r will be a fixed point of FPI with a particular g(x)."**

Comment: "**with a particular `g(x)`**" is the keyword.  You need to **modify** `g(x)` so that you're finding the root of the equation.  With that, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small note before I start.  There's a typo in your `g` function.  I'm assuming you meant `(7/2)*` not `(7/2).`.  I also had to edit your code to allow the power operation to work element-wise:

```
g = @(x)(5-((5/2).*exp(x/2))-((7/2)*x.^2)-3*x).^1/3;
```

Doing some initial tests with this corrected function match up to what you're getting.

---

In any case, your use of fixed-point iterations to find the roots of an equation is incorrect.  Before I go into what you need to do to fix it, I'd like to cover how fixed-point iteration works so that you (as well as everyone else who reads this post) understands where I'm coming from.

Fixed-point iterations is based on an initial input value `x0`.  You then repeatedly calculate what the output of this value is once you submit this into a function, then **reuse** the output as input at the next iteration.  Concretely, a fixed point iteration scheme performs this:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

Ideally, after some iterations, we would want the iterations to converge to some value `x` such that:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

The above is the very definition of a fixed point.  To do this to find roots is not (natively) supported because finding the root of an equation contradicts what a fixed point is supposed to be.  The definition of a root is when `f(x) = 0` and this is **not** a fixed-point **unless `x=0`**.  If you want to use fixed-point iterations to find the roots, then you must change the way the function `f` is structured.  This leads us to the classical iterative root finding technique called [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which also uses fixed-point iterations to find the roots of functions, but the function `f(x)` is different.

I won't go into the derivation of Newton's Method, but this is what you do instead at each iteration:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

`f(x)` is the function and `f'(x)` is the derivative of `f(x)`.  If we replaced the right hand side with a new function `g(x)`, you would thus perform fixed-point iterations on the function `g(x)` and the result after convergence is the root you're looking for.  Concretely, if:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

then:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

and thus:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

... and `x` is a root of the function `f(x)` if:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration)</sup>

Therefore, you will need to modify your code so that it doesn't take a function handle anymore.  It will have to take a **symbolic** version because you need to take the derivative of the function.

Bearing that in mind, this is the modification you'd need to make to your code in order to get it to work:

```
%//Program 1.2 Fixed-Point Iteration via Newton's Method
%//Computes approximate root of g(x)=0
%//Input: symbolic function g, starting guess x0, 
%//       number of steps k
%//Output: Approximate solution xc

format long g; %// For precision
x(1)=x0;
gp = diff(g); %// Change
for i=1:k
    gval = double(subs(g, 'x', x(i))); %// Change
    gpval = double(subs(gp, 'x', x(i))); %// Change
    x(i+1)= x(i) - (gval/gpval); %// Change
end
xc=x(k+1);
y = double(subs(g, 'x', x)); %// Change
disp('                        x0                      g(x0)');
disp([x' y'])
```

What's different is that inside the function, you find the derivative symbolically with [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html).  Also, when you want to substitute values into the function, you need to use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) then cast the result to `double`.  I'm also assuming that your function is with respect to the variable `x`.

The third-last line of code converts all of those `x` values that you accumulated into a `double` array for display.

To run this code, you'd do:

```
syms x;
g = (5-((5/2)*exp(x/2))-((7/2)*x^2)-3*x)^1/3;
xc = fpi(g, 0.5, 20);
```

Take note that you don't need the element-wise operators anymore, as we're dealing with symbolic equations.

We get:

```
>> fpi(g, 0.5, 20)
                        x0                      g(x0)
                       0.5        -0.195021180573118
         0.427814775036064       -0.0067677938874851
          0.42512303212814     -9.38738903072792e-06
         0.425119288112029     -1.81600035806892e-11
         0.425119288104786     -5.28061163184459e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
         0.425119288104786      1.52806116318446e-17
```

So one of the roots is equal to `0.425119288104786`.  The right column tells you what the value at `g(x)` is evaluated at for each iteration, and you can see that it's very small... almost 0.  That's the definition of a root more or less.

Comment: Thank you for everything, @rayryeng! One last question, if r = g(r), must f(r) = 0 (must f(r) be equal to 0) ?

Comment: Very close.  If you're using Newton's method, `g(r) = r - f(r)/f'(r)`.  `r` is a root if `f(r)/f'(r) = 0`.  Newton's Method works with fixed point iterations to minimize this term at each iteration.